# Show that $S_n \cong \Bbb{P}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

This is problem 1.45 of Rotman's *Introduction to theory of groups*.

> Let $k$ be a field and denote the columns of the $n \times n$ identity matrix $E$ by $\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_n$. A permutation matrix $P$ is obtained from E by permuting its columns, that is, the columns of $P$ are $\epsilon_{\alpha 1},..., \epsilon_{\alpha n}$ for some $\alpha \in S_n$. Prove that the set of all permutation matrices over $k$ is a group isomorphic to $S_n$.

So I called this set $\Bbb{P}$ and verified it is a where the inverse of every element $P$ is its transpose matrix $P^t$. However when trying to verify that $\Bbb{P} \cong S_n$ I got stuck. I tried by defining $f:S_n \to \Bbb{P}
$ as

1)$f(\alpha)=P_{\alpha}$ where $P_{\alpha}$ is the matrix who´s columns are exactly $\epsilon_{\alpha 1},..., \epsilon_{\alpha n}$.

But $f$ defined in this manner is not a homomorphism.

2)$f(\alpha)=P^{t}_{\alpha}$ the same problem

3)$f(\alpha)=P_{\alpha^{-1}}$ the same problem.

So this guesses were in such a way randomly selected. Is there any way I can criteriously pursue the desired morphism?

Comment: I think 1) is a nearly a homomorphism. $P_\alpha[i,j]\not=0 \iff j = \alpha(i)$. Then $(P_\alpha P_\beta)[i,j] = \sum_k P_\alpha[i,k]P_\beta[k,j]$ but $P_\alpha[i,k]P_\beta[k,j]\not= 0 \iff \alpha[i,k]\not= 0 \land P_\beta[k,j]\not= 0\iff k=\alpha(i) \land j=\beta(k)$ so that $\sum_k P_\alpha[i,k]P_\beta[k,j]$ is non-zero iff $\exists k, k = \alpha(i) \land j=\beta(k)$ or, equivalently, $\beta(\alpha(i))=j$. So $P_\alpha P_\beta = P_{\beta\alpha}$.

Comment: Then $Q_\alpha=P_\alpha^{-1}$ yields $Q_{\alpha\beta}=P_{\alpha\beta}^{-1}=(P_\beta P_\alpha)^{-1}=P_\alpha^{-1} P_\beta^{-1}=Q_\alpha Q_\beta$. The same thing would work with $R_\alpha=P_\alpha^T$.

Comment: In fact $P_\alpha^{\rm T} = P_{\alpha^{-1}}$ for a permutation matrix $P_\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P$ denote the given set of permutation matrices. We have a map $f:P \to S_n$ given by $\pi e_i = e_{f(\pi)i}$, where $e_1, \dots, e_n$ is the standard basis of $k^n$. Clearly $f$ is a bijection, and it's immediate that $f(\pi \pi') = f(\pi)f(\pi')$. It follows that $P$ is a group, and the map $f$ is an isomorphism. (If it isn't clear, note that the group structure on $P$ follows from the fact that $\pi\pi' = f^{-1}(f(\pi)f(\pi'))$. In particular, inverses $\pi^{-1} = f(\pi^{-1})$ exist for all $\pi$.)

Comment: Im kind of mixed up when you say, $f$ is given by $\pi e_i = e_{f (\pi) i} $

Comment: @JoaquinLiniado: What about it?

Comment: Given a matrix $A \in P $ what is $f (A) $?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking; what you wrote in the first comment is exactly the definition of $f$.

Comment: Which is exactly what I don't understand. You say that $f:P \to S_n$ so $f $ takes a permutation matrix $A \in P$ and transforms it into a permutation $\alpha \in S_n $. I would write this as $f (A)=\alpha$. Im not being able to see how the expression in my first comment is analogous to this one.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're asking. For a given $\pi\in P$, we have $\pi e_i = e_j$ for some $j = j(i)$; that permutation $i \to j(i)$ is by defintion $f(\pi)$.